# Autofill a formula based on data entered in an adjacent cel

Tags: microsoft-excel

For a sheet that I am creating for a race team I am trying to write a simple formula: when I enter a lap time in B8, then I would like C8 will auto populate with remaining fuel in the tank (in C7 I have the tank size, 120L, and in C6 I have litres per lap 2.3). C8 should then show 117.7
How would I write this formula?
Then when I enter the next lap time in B9, it auto populates the remaining fuel now from C8 minus the constant in C6 (litres per lap) in C9.  C9 should then show 115.4 etc for the remaining laps.
Thank You

Answer (score 2):

C8 formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B8),"",C7-$C$6)
```

Drag it down and you're done. If you don't have a time in the laptime column, then it will be blank. Else, it will populate your liters remaining.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Comment: Please consider making as an approved answer,  thanks.